# How to filter c++ compiler warnings after the fact

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I routinely submit R libraries with a C++ component to a third party repository (CRAN) that compiles them on various platforms and distributes the binaries to users.  I do not control the compiler flags used on all the platforms.

From time to time the different compilers on this platform find bugs in my code and alert me.  However, when I look through the build logs, they're full of repetitive warning messages, mainly from libraries I don't control (e.g. boost still supports deprecated auto_ptr).  The sea of warning messages makes it hard to find the actual errors.

Each warning helpfully lists the flag that spawned it, but each warning is a multi-line chain (in file X\n included from file Y\n included from...) which makes simple filtering solutions like 'grep' and 'awk' less simple.

How can I parse the compiler output to remove all the warning lines, based on a string build from the flag that generated them (as `[-Wsign-compare]` or `[-Wdeprecated-auto-ptr]`). That way I will only have the compiler errors.

As an example, here is one warning.  The output contains thousands of such warnings, each with different numbers of lines.  The multi-line nature of the output would appear to make line-based filtering tools (e.g. grep, awk) unsuitable for filtering.

```
/home/hornik/lib/R/Library/3.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:256:65: warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 template< class T, class R > struct sp_enable_if_auto_ptr< std::auto_ptr< T >, R >
                                                                 ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iomanip:43,
                 from /home/hornik/lib/R/Library/3.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/BH/include/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:12,
                 from /home/hornik/lib/R/Library/3.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/BH/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:14,
                 from /home/hornik/lib/R/Library/3.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/Boom/include/cpputil/portable_math.hpp:43,
                 from /home/hornik/lib/R/Library/3.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/Boom/include/cpputil/math_utils.hpp:25,
                 from /home/hornik/lib/R/Library/3.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/Boom/include/LinAlg/Vector.hpp:31,
                 from /home/hornik/lib/R/Library/3.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/Boom/include/r_interface/boom_r_tools.hpp:24,
                 from model_manager.h:20,
                 from bsts.cc:20:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:51:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
                            ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Doesn't `grep -v` do what you want ? Maybe I did not understand the question...

Comment: grep -v will filter out individual lines that contain some sort of a pattern.  But the output I'm getting is in the form of multi-line error messages.  For example, this is one error:

Comment: grep -v will filter out individual lines that contain some sort of a pattern.  But the output I'm getting is in the form of multi-line error messages.  For example:
<pre>
    In file included from /home/.../BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:28:0,
    from /home/.../BH/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
    from /home/...smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:355:33: warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     explicit shared_count( std::auto_ptr<Y> & r ): pi_( new sp_counted_impl_p<Y>( r.get() ) )
</pre>

Comment: Your comment is mostly unreadable, although it seems to hold some valuable information on what you want to achieve. Could you edit your question and add that compiler output, correctly formatted? It'll be clearer.

Comment: Thanks @kebs.  Updated.

Comment: I reworded the question so it is now be suitable for SO. The point is truly "how can I do this".